# How to enable other languages for MailChimp List Subscribe Plugin?

Tags: localization, internationalization, wordpress, mailchimp

I have translated the MailChimp provided [**MailChimp List Subscribe Form**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp/) plugin for wordpress.

I used poEdit to edit. At `wp-config.php` I have language set as `ar_SA`. Which works for the themes I have used in two Bilingual sites. But the mo file had to be renamed to `ar.mo`

I got two problems:

1. While updating the catalog poEdit crashes. But I could save the `.po`
   and generated `.mo` successfully.
2. The translated `.mo` doesn't appear for the confirmation success or error messages through the Ajax calls which its supposed to.

I am submitting my `.po` file link here for experts to view. I have saved the settings for translation in the files.

[Translated Bangla.po file](https://github.com/zenideas/wp-mailchimp/blob/develop/po/mailchimp_i18n-bn_BD.po)   ||    [Translated Arabic.po file](https://github.com/zenideas/wp-mailchimp/blob/develop/po/mailchimp_i18n-ar_SA.po)

Comment: I have put the `.mo` files in the plugin's `po/` folder and also tried putting them in the `wp-content/languages` folder. But the other languages doesn't appear in the frontend.

Comment: I had to use `ar.mo` probably because the qTranslate plugin I have used changes the language at the HTML as `<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">`. Arabic language isn't listed in this plugin as `ar_SA`.